# is there a simple way to parse XML and find a needed element?

Tags: android, xml, parsing

Usually when parsing XML i have to create all those lists with nodes, childs and what not.

Maybe there's a more simple way?...

For example I have a document that contains a few elements which id starts with "patch".

```
<rect id="patchW" x="48" display="none" fill="#993333" width="48" height="75"/>
```

And what I need is to make a list that would contain **id** ( of the elements that start with "patch" ), **x** and **y** ( if not present, then 0 ).

What do you think would be the best way of doing it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your best bet is [SAX](http://www.saxproject.org/), which will fire events such as "start of element," "end of element," etc.  Just listen to the start element events, and add the information you care about into a list every time you get an element whose ID starts with patch.  Also, SAX is extremely fast - a lot of other XML parsing libraries, such as DOM, are built on top of SAX.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a Parser such as [JSOUP](http://jsoup.org/)

Very simple to use and works tremendously well

Answer (score 0):

you should use [Xstream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/tutorial.html).It is useful.